# Prevent page refresh after upload file in Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

I dont want to refresh the whole page after completing upload.

This is my VF Page,it directly close the modal box and refresh the whole page after I click Upload button.I dont want it to refresh or close the modal box until I click CLose.However it successfully upload file,it just behavior that I would like to change.

```
<div class="modal" id="attModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="attModal" aria-hidden="true">
        <apex:outputPanel id="uploadForm">
        <apex:form >
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" >&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalQuesLabel">File Attachment</h4>
            </div>
            <p class="errorMessage" style="color:red"><apex:outputText value="{!attErrorMsg}"/></p>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="hidden" name="resId" id="resId" value=""  class="form-control"/>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label  class="control-label">1. Select the File</label> 
                    <apex:inputFile value="{!newAtt.body}" filename="{!newAtt.name}"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label  class="control-label">2. Attach File</label>&nbsp;           
                  <apex:commandLink styleclass="btn-bootstrap btn-primary btn-sm" action="{!uploadFile}" immediate="false" status="loadingStatus" >
                    Upload
                  </apex:commandLink>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn-bootstrap btn-default btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal" data-loading-text="Loading...">Close</button> 
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </apex:form>
        </apex:outputPanel>
      </div>
```

This is my controller

```
public PageReference uploadFile(){
        newAtt.ParentId = header.Id;


        if( newAtt.Name != null ){
            Integer s = 0;
            newAtt.ParentId = header.Id;
            Blob temp = newAtt.Body;
            s = temp.size();
            Double size = (s / (1024*1024));

            if(size > 5){
                attErrorMsg = 'You cannot upload file more than 5MB size';
                newAtt =  new Attachment();  // done to prevent passing back to viewstate
                return null;
            }
            else{
                try{
                    insert newAtt;
                }
                catch(Exception ex){
                    attErrorMsg= 'File attach error:'+ ex.getMessage();
                    return null;
                }
            }

            newAtt = new Attachment();
            closeAttPopup = 'true';

          return null;

        }
        else{
            attErrorMsg = 'Please SELECT a file to upload.';
            newAtt =  new Attachment();  
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the current approach, having the `commandLink`, the form will be automatically submitted to the server and you can't prevent that considering that you want to know whether the upload was successful or not.

A better way of doing that will be to switch to Visualforce Remoting, push the file to the server and manipulate your DOM based on the response. This is a great post that explains how all that ties together - [Uploading Attachments to Salesforce using Javascript Remoting](https://forceadventure.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/uploading-attachments-to-salesforce-using-javascript-remoting/)

Comment: i will try this one and will update the result here.

Comment: Yes, I tried this and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Use rerender to refresh parts of the page you want.

```
<apex:outputPanel id="areaToRefresh">
     <!--refreshed part -->
<apex:outputPanel>
<apex:commandLink rerender="areaToRefresh">
```

Comment: I tried..it is not working.

Comment: Here is a sample from Salesforce help https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_ajax_partial_page_updates.htm

Comment: yes, rerender working fine but not able to work with this upload.